# How to check for numeric value in Julia

Tags: types, julia

I want to determine if a value is numeric or not before trying to use a function on it. As a specific example:

```
z = [1.23,"foo"]
for val in z
    if isnumeric(val)
        round(z)
    end
end
```

Here `isnumeric()` is a function that I don't think exists in Julia. I can think of a few different ways this *might* be done, but I would like to see some suggestions for the "best" way.

Comment: Your use case isn't totally clear, so it may make sense to use dispatch to control what gets called for different types of values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I *think* the preferred idiom is

```
isa(val, Number)
```

Normally you are interested in rounding floats, in which case

```
isa(val, AbstractFloat)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can check the element's type like this:

```
typeof(val)<:Number
```

The `:<` operator checks if a type is a subtype of another.

Here is a very helpful chart giving an overview of numeric types in Julia: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Types

Comment: Didn't choose as the answer because using the built-in `isa()` is a better approach. However, your link to the Julia types diagram is excellent.